# How big do artificial biomes need to be to spawn monsters?

Tags: terraria

I'm building my artificial biomes in Terraria so I can farm certain things and have enemies spawn. The question is how big do the biomes need to be?

So far I've built a crimson, underground jungle, surface jungle and a desert but none of them are spawning monsters. I've read the Guide on Artificial biomes on Terraria wiki and many other forms but I have not found my answer. Can someone please give me detailed information?

I have enough blocks to where the background and music changes for each biome and yet still no monsters.

Answer (score 7):

The Terraria wiki does have an answer on how big many of these biomes have to be:

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Artificial_biomes

For example, snow biome requires 300 snow blocks, ice blocks, or snow bricks.

Generally, you'll want to keep adding blocks until the background changes.

You can also try a Water Candle to increase monster spawn rate.

Comment: I have enough blocks to where the background and music changes for each biome and yet still no monsters.

Comment: @Monique You may need to make it slightly bigger, and then to walk off to the side a bit to give them some space outside of your screen region to spawn.  Which biome are you making specifically?

Comment: I'm making a crimson biome. I just made a small area with enough blocks to change the background and music. Which was why I was wondering if it needed to be a specific size. I also made a few other biomes but none of them have spawned monsters and I know I've given them enough time to spawn.

Comment: Enemies will only ever spawn off-screen. If your artificial biome is small enough that it fits in your entire screen, you need to move so that at least part of it is off-screen first.

Comment: By off screen I'm taking you mean my computer screen not my mini map. When I'm in my house the only thing I see is my house none of the biomes. The same goes for the biomes. If I'm in my desert biome I can't see any of the other biomes. Even when I leave my house all together no enemies spawn.

Comment: On my mini map though I can see everything.

Comment: Then your house/NPC's may be too close to the biomes and are stopping all enemies from spawning.

Comment: 1 way to see if your biome is valid (at least this is what i do) is to set up the artificial biome near a nomral tree. Then you  need to let the thing evolve "give it some time" if the Tree has changed into a tree of that biome you are good to go! Take a water Candle and place it in the middel of your biome then whait there :D (make shure that the biome is bigger than your screen)

Comment: How far away from the NPC's do the biomes have to be before enemies will spawn?

Comment: Also do the biomes have to be "open" meaning no ceilings and no doors?

Comment: I'm not sure if it needs to be open, but if you have ceilings and doors with a background wall, the game might think it is a house and not spawn anything in there.

Answer (score 2):

Monsters only spawn in a certain distance in tiles from the player i.e. between 62 - 84 blocks to the left or right of the player and between 35 - 47 up and down. Its not enough that the biome has to be off screen but it has to be in between these distances. So either make the biomes bigger i.e. 168 * 94 blocks with the player in the centre or dig out the middle and have the edges the biome you want.

Answer (score 1):

I can't even get the background or music to change. But that didn't worry me and it shouldn't worry you because to my surprise in my artificial snow biome failure a zombie eskimo spawned.
Basically it doesn't matter what size the biome is, mobs will still spawn just slower. However the bigger it is the more it will spawn monsters.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Review the Terraria Wiki for the exact specifications for creating an artificial biome. If you do encounter any anomalies, ie. enemies from different biomes spawning, it's because most biomes need only 1 block to spawn enemies and plants. For example, you need a minimum of 1000 blocks to create a fully artificial desert biome, complete with background and music. However, 1 block of sand can still spawn waterleafs, antlions, vultures, and even hardmode NPCs.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer, but to help you in construction, listen for the change in music.  Once you start to hear the biome-specific music, you know that you've successfully created an artificial biome.

Comment: I have enough blocks to where the background and music changes for each biome and yet still no monsters.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to lay down about 1000+ tiles on either side of you, obviously using the blocks of the biome you want to create.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried the same with making an underground corrupted biome. The world's in hardmode and I want the cursed flames spell, so I placed some ebonstone in a cave and, slowly but surely, it turned into underground corruption. I'd say this is a good set up for any artificial biomes.